Expo Router Website opening a specific page with an ID variable
I have a website based in expo router that have the following structure
App
-Tabs - Index.tsx
- pages - [id].tsx
When I run "npx expo export --platform web" and I take the dist files to my webserver, the website runs perfect, without any problem, if I click in one of the users open without problem the profile on the user https//domain.com/pages/90 (90 is the id of an example user profile).
This work great when I go from the index component to the [id] page.
BUT I need to have the chance to go directly to https//domain.com/pages/90 and have the chance to open the profile of the user but I don't know how! I tried changing useGlobalSearchParams rather than useLocalSearchParams, but not very clear of how to do this.
If someone can help me would be AWESOME!
I'm expecting to share the link https://thegrapeviner.com/pages/86 and the people be able to see the profile of that user. Today only work when the the component onpress:
onPress={() =>
            router.push({
              pathname: "/pages/[id]",
              params: {
                id: idService,
              },
            })

